# Use Custom OpenVINO Operations throw an error : what(): Operation: output_name0 of type Identity(op::v0) is not supported

Tags: operators, type-inference, custom-function, openvino, post-processing

[I customized a class by referring to the official openvino document.](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_Extensibility_UG_add_openvino_ops.html)
[This is my class.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkRSJ.png)
[code copy from here.](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/tree/2022.2.0/docs/template_extension/new)
When I use this class in Post processing Customize operations, it throws an error: what():  Operation: output_name0 of type Identity(op::v0) is not supported

```
    ppp.output().postprocess()
//  .convert_layout("NHWC")
//  .convert_element_type(ov::element::u8)
    .custom([](const ov::Output<ov::Node>& node) {
         return std::make_shared<TemplateExtension::Identity>(node);
        });
```

[Here I learn how to use openvino Post-processing Customize operations.](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_OV_UG_Preprocessing_Details.html)

Please help me how to use my custom operator in Post-processing Customize operations!!

Answer (score 0):

`return std::make_shared<TemplateExtension::Identity>(node);` doesn't contain any value. You need to use `return std::make_shared<ov::opset8::Abs>(node);`.